# Android/Java. Maps API. Как изменить текст InfoWindow при событии onInfoWindowClick?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, карты, textview, marker

В методе getInfoWindow задаю изначально текст..

```
 map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

                        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker, null);

                        TextView info= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info);

                        info.setText("1");

                        return v;

                    }
```

Затем в методе onInfoWindowClick хочу заменить этот текст

`public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                           ...`

Вопрос: Как теперь получить доступ к тексту в InfoWindow? и Как заменить текст?

т.е. при клике на InfoWindow его текст должен быть заменен на новый..

Answer (score 1):

Вот такое решение не подходит? Только тут клик по маркеру.

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.setTitle("123");
            }
        });
```

Comment: нее..мне нужно как то получить то самое InfoWindow - это вьюв кастомный и вот как то туда присваивать.. не знаю как это сделать..